# ThreeJS full scene minimal rotation

Tags: three.js

I want to know on how does this website (http://www.cryptarismission.com/) do it's scene face to different directions when you move your mouse over.

On their home page, it seems that when you move your mouse, the scene follows smoothly in a very small amount of axis rotation.

What is the idea behind this thing using Three.js? I know that you can rotate object, scene or the camera but I am not sure what to rotate. I'm thinking of rotating the whole scene container but I don't know if that's good.

Comment: you can refer this example:https://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_materials_bumpmap

Comment: Thanks, that's a great reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can either change camera position and call lookAt in every loop depending on mouse position or change whole scene rotation. Here is how first approach works.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>ThreeJS full scene minimal rotation</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/96/three.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <canvas></canvas>
</body>

<script>
    var camera, scene, renderer, stats, windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2,
        windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2,
        mouseX = 0,
        mouseY = 0;

    init();
    animate();

    function init() {
        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 2000);
        camera.position.set(30, 30, 30)
        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        scene.add(new THREE.Mesh(
            new THREE.BoxGeometry(5, 5, 5),
            new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 })
        ));

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, canvas: document.querySelector('canvas') });
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
        window.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
    }

    function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
        mouseX = (event.clientX - windowHalfX) / 10;
        mouseY = (event.clientY - windowHalfY) / 10;
    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        render();
    }

    function render() {
        camera.position.x += (mouseX - camera.position.x) * .05;
        camera.position.y += (-mouseY - camera.position.y) * .05;
        camera.lookAt(scene.position);
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Tomasz, exactly a starting point of what I am looking for.

Comment: @ArchieHerbias Glad I could help